# Editing Path Instead of Copying the DLL in a post-build event

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to use dll files from OpenCV. To locate the dll files, instead of copying the dll file in a post-build event, a guy on YouTube did the same thing by going to System-> System Variables -> Edit Path -> Add YourLocationToDLLFile.

My code runs fine by editing my Path variable. I do not understand how editing the Path variable gives me the same result as copying the dll file in a post-build event.

Comment: The OS needs to be able to find those DLLs when your program runs.  The best way is to put them in the same directory as your program, that is where it looks first.  About one of the worst ways is to change the configuration of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I presume, since OpenCV is C++, your application is also *unmanaged*. In this case you should consult [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

PATH directories are used as the last resort for DLL searcher to try locating the requested DLL. That's why it works for you.

Mind you, this is, obviously, good only for your local development, when you deploy your application, make sure it is properly packed with all the necessary dependencies, including OpenCV.